# Linking to another page when user checks a checkbox with PHP

Tags: php, html

I've been creating a login system, and the logging in/registering is handled via a single form to start. Users check a checkbox when they aren't registered yet, so I need to change a redirect with PHP, as that is what I'm familiar with. I've not seen anything that helps with this.

Comment: Can you post your checkbox code here?

Answer (score 2):

Users check a checkbox when they are registered yet

I hope this code works in your project :
........

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="Overdue.php?i=0" 
name="checket" onClick="if (this.checked) { window.location = this.value; }">
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" value="1" onclick="window.location='redirect_pagename.php';">
```

Just add an `onclick` event to your `checkbox` to `navigate` user to another page.